# Netty ClosedChannelException When Asynchronize Process My Received Message

Tags: netty

When I receive a new request, I will put this `MessageEvent` into a `LinkedBlockingQueue`;
another thread is running to read `MessageEvent` from this `LinkedBlockingQueue`, so I process the `messageEvent` and write to the client. But when I write to the client, an exception occurs.

Here is my code:

```
@Override
public void messageReceived(ChannelHandlerContext ctx, MessageEvent e) {
    LogConsole.info(e.toString());
    messageReceivedQueue.addReceivedMessage(e);
}

public void run() {
   MessageEvent  e = messageReceivedQueue.get()；       
   e.getChannel().write(e.getMessage());
}
```

And here are the errors I get:

```
java.nio.channels.ClosedChannelException
    at org.jboss.netty.channel.socket.nio.NioWorker.cleanUpWriteBuffer(NioWorker.java:645)
    at org.jboss.netty.channel.socket.nio.NioWorker.writeFromUserCode(NioWorker.java:372)
    at org.jboss.netty.channel.socket.nio.NioServerSocketPipelineSink.handleAcceptedSocket(NioServerSocketPipelineSink.java:137)
    at org.jboss.netty.channel.socket.nio.NioServerSocketPipelineSink.eventSunk(NioServerSocketPipelineSink.java:76)
    at org.jboss.netty.channel.Channels.write(Channels.java:632)
    at org.jboss.netty.handler.codec.oneone.OneToOneEncoder.handleDownstream(OneToOneEncoder.java:70)
    at org.jboss.netty.channel.Channels.write(Channels.java:611)
    at org.jboss.netty.channel.Channels.write(Channels.java:578)
    at org.jboss.netty.channel.AbstractChannel.write(AbstractChannel.java:251)
    at com.bankht.cis.tcs.service.executor.adapter.AbstractMessageAdapter$ProcessWorker.run(AbstractMessageAdapter.java:97)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.runTask(Unknown Source)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Unknown Source)
```

Answer (score 0):

This tells you that the Channel was closed in the meantime. There is not much you can do about it as a client may close the socket all the time.

Comment: thks，you are right. I find out that the channel was closed before i write to client. but when i write to the client in messageReceived method ,it will send to the client successfully.I'm confused.            like this                                                               @Override
public void messageReceived(ChannelHandlerContext ctx, MessageEvent e) {
    e.getChannel().write("resp：" + e.getMessage().toString());
}